# Celery daemonization with Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, heroku, daemon, django-celery

I'm new to Python and really trying to learn things as I go. I have a Python script that pulls data from different sites and displays it to the public via a website. I am using Django with Heroku distribution.

I need to automatically run my scripts in the morning to update the information. I saw that celery was the best option to do this. I now have a working example of celery, and believe that I have it properly configured with Django. However, I need to also go through a process called daemonization as per here: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/daemonizing.html so that my celery workers can operate in the background.

This is where I'm stumped, and can't find any step-by-step tutorials for this one. I think I need all of these file for things to work:

```
/etc/init.d/celeryd
/etc/defaults/celery
/etc/default/celerybeat
/project/celery.py
/project/__init__.py
```

I have all of these files starting in the root directory, where `manage.py` is located
I believe I have the `celery.py` and `__init__.py` files configured correctly. Here they are: celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery


# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project.settings')

app = Celery('project')

# Using a string here means the worker doesn't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks()


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

and init.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ['celery_app']
```

I'm not sure how to properly configure the other two files. Here is what I have for `celeryd`:

```
CELERYD_NODES=4
CELERY_BIN="project/celery"
CELERY_APP="project"
CELERYD_CHDIR="project/"

# Extra command-line arguments to the worker
#CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=300 --concurrency=8"
# Configure node-specific settings by appending node name to arguments:
#CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=300 -c 8 -c:worker2 4 -c:worker3 2 -Ofair:worker1"

# Set logging level to DEBUG
#CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL="DEBUG"

# %n will be replaced with the first part of the nodename.
CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/%n%I.log"
CELERYD_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery/%n.pid"
CELERYD_USER="celery"
CELERYD_GROUP="celery"
CELERY_CREATE_DIRS=1
```

and here is the `celerybeat` file:

```
# Absolute or relative path to the 'celery' command:
CELERY_BIN="project/celery"
#CELERY_BIN="/virtualenvs/def/bin/celery"

# App instance to use
# comment out this line if you don't use an app
CELERY_APP="project"
# or fully qualified:
#CELERY_APP="proj.tasks:app"

# Where to chdir at start.
CELERYBEAT_CHDIR="/project/"

# Extra arguments to celerybeat
#CELERYBEAT_OPTS="--schedule=/var/run/celery/celerybeat-schedule"
```

I'm also not sure exactly where I'm supposed  to put the following line:

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="settings"
```

I'm not exactly sure what goes in `/etc/defaults/celery` or if I even need it.
I believe I also have to make it so that my tasks file has main file for `CELERY_BEAT` options somehow. Haven't gotten this far yet but I should be able to put the crontab option here right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Heroku so you do not need to do **any** of this. Just put the celery command in your Procfile.

Comment: Thank you very much. Didn't think to check Heroku for compatibility.